# Compute the volume of the region $R$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $R=\{(x,y,z):3x^2 \leq z \leq 3, \ -z \leq y \leq z\}$ and compute the volume $\text{Volume}(R).$

Plotting the first inequality:

[image]

and since $y$ varies between $-z$ and $z$, the region is just a cylindric paraboloid bounded by the parabola $z=3x^2,$ the planes $z=3$, $y=-z$ and $y=z$. Now it remains to get the bounds for the trippleintegral.

Clearly $ -1\leq x \leq 1$ and it's already given that $-z \leq y \leq z$. But It's also given that (and it's evident from the figure above) that $3x^2 \leq z \leq 3$. So

$$I=\iiint_R1 \ dzdydz=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-z}^{z}\int_{3x^2}^{3}1 \ dzdydx= 8z.$$

Now I got a my answer in terms of $z$, but this is ok since I don't know the bounds explicitly for $y$.

Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "decompose" the integral like this with those boundaries for the variables. When you do such "decomposition" of the integral you are actually first projecting the region onto the $xy$-plane and afterwards on $x$-line and so on. When you do the projection onto the $xy$-plane it can't be dependent on $z$.

To get around this you can express $y$ in terms of $x$ using the inequality $3x^2 \le z \le 3$. However a better solution would be to project the region onto the $xz$-plane first and afterwards onto the $x$-line. Then the solution would be:

$$\iiint_R1 \ dzdydz=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{3x^2}^{3}\int_{-z}^{z}1 \ dydzdx$$

Now just evaluate the integral, which shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation.